# Failing in reading and displaying a text file

Tags: java, file, input, line, display

I can read in one value and I get it almost right but this is where I am stuck at. I've searched everywhere and looked through my entire book

Comment: For example, this is what I need it to display but I can't and am on the verge of giving up. https://gyazo.com/4d3487c2ab253bd0379f9c620bfd8b94

Comment: This is what the .txt looks like https://gyazo.com/bf7da1096e9e91a6c4a679cceec81159

Answer (score 0):

For a start

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= TOTAL_CUSTOMERS; i++)
  {
   while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
```

This inner `while` loop is readinf through the whole of your file, so the outer `for` should not be required.

Secondly, (we do not know what the file contents are) all that is being returned from the file is one line at a time, how this relates to a `policy` is unknown to us, but it appears that eight lines == one policy.  You could loop this in your `while` loop to group (and construct a purposely built) class with this eight lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String[] customerDetails = new String[9];
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_CUSTOMERS; i++){
    for(int j = 0 ; inputFile.hasNext() && j < 9 ; j++){
        customerDetails[j] = inputFile.nextLine();
    }
    displayMessage(customerDetails);
    customerDetails = new String[9];
}

inputFile.close();
```

You will have to change the logic in `displayMessage()`.

Comment: I get NullPointerException when I try using that code, this is how I setup my displaymessage() https://gyazo.com/7bc2f3baf6152759582bc65d14f4d5c4

Comment: You are using the array to get 9 values while the array size is only 8. and FYI you should select the value of arrays as `custoerDetails[0]` , `customerDetails[1]`. I will update the answer with the size as 9

Comment: I'm getting this for all 6 print outs https://gyazo.com/166c50e06421f0c44a65626bf3cfbd5f , my updated code is this though. http://pastebin.com/YvPSHUZ5 . Thank you for helping me, I am feeling very helpless even with reading all the chapters in my book.

Comment: Sorry there were some errors in the code I pasted. I didnot test the code before posting. The updated code should work. I have tested it. I went through your code and you should remove the `for` loop in the `displayMessage()`. And also read about debugging a code in IDEs like Eclipse , Netbeans

Comment: Thanks alot! that worked and I managed to get displayMessage() to work. I'm on the final part where I have to do some calculations, am I able to take the int's out of the string[] array? This is what I need to be able to do https://gyazo.com/288b3240fa1daf9ecb5a04fa23343b65

Comment: use `Integer.parseInt(<String>)`

Comment: Sorry, i'm still a noob but how can I pass data that was read in from the file and pass it into other methods to do calculations?

Comment: You have passed the data you read from a file into the `displayMessage()`. Pass the data in the same manner to other methods.

Comment: Is this how I should pass the data? https://gyazo.com/f2786dde0f6fcce85cf7ebe1b884c2ed

Comment: You are trying to assign a `String` to an `int`. This will not work so you have to cast it. `Integer.parseInt(<String>)` is used to cast a `String` to `int`. You should replace `<String>` with the string you use in the code. So replace your code with  `int height = integer.parseInt(customerDetails[6]); int weight = Integer.parseInt(customerDetails[7]);` and remove the line `Integer.parseInt(<customerDetails>)`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand it better now, and I managed to get it working, I think I should be able to finish the rest myself.

Comment: I've got everything working now except for the last piece of code, I need it to add up all the premPrices it calculates to a total, this is my code and that is the error i get at the bottom https://gyazo.com/fcec45ddc7968e028e0b06d0cc448bf1

Comment: Check if `customerDetails[4]` is `null`. Please tell which line throws the error.